# Is the year "5778" that will come into effect on 1 Tishrei (tomorrow), six months early or six months late?

Tags: halacha, calendar, rosh-hashanah-new-year, rosh-chodesh-new-month

Is the world at least six months older or younger than 5,778 Years?

Is the year "5778" that will come into effect on 1 Tishrei (tomorrow), six months early or six months late, knowing that the New Year (mentioned in the Torah) takes place on 1 Nisan, which the Torah calls "Rishon HaShanah" (Shemot 12,2) רִאשׁוֹן... הַשָּׁנָה?

The rabbis believe that 5778 is based on the creation of the world (that is, 5,778 years from the creation of the world), which they believed began in the month of Nisan, not on Tishrei.

Is the introduction of the rabbinical dating (which tomorrow will be 5778, in the month of Tishrei, which the rabbis have every prerogative to do) six months late?

Comment: are you subscribing to the view that the world was created in Nisan? This piece might help http://www.yutorah.org/togo/roshhashana/articles/Rosh_Hashanah_To-Go_-_5770_Rabbi_Reiss.pdf

Comment: But first in the counting of the months doesn't necessarily equate to the first in the counting for the year, or the anniversary of the creation of the world. If you count from when Nisan was established as the first month, the 5778 is the wrong number.

Comment: @rosends when was tishre established as the first month of rosh hashana?

Comment: 1 Nissan 5778 will be the first day of the Year 3330. So too 14 Shevat 5778 will be the first day of year 2018. Different year systems have different epochs.

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/63897/759

Comment: @DoubleAA when did you come into the world? It is possible you will say, you came into the world on your birthday. That may be so, but the fact is, you came into the world on the day you were conceived, which is several months before your birth. Likewise, the rabbis may have introduced, in this case 5778, on 1 Tishrei, but in fact, 5778, already presented itself on 1 Nisan.

Comment: @ninamag No. 5778 did not present itself on 1 Nissan. It could be that 1 Nissan was the 5778th anniversary of the preconception of the world (a claim which has nothing to do with the counting of months), but that doesn't mean the year started then. Epochs are conventions and the convention is to start in Tishrei. Anything else is just [bad communication](https://xkcd.com/169/).

Comment: You've now presented multiple reasons for what you are asking (understanding the chosen convention, opinions the world was created in Nissan, opinions the world was conceived in Nissan, counting of months begins in Nissan, the verse says the year starts in Nissan). So I'm closing this quesiton till you can figure out what you want to know.

Comment: "which the Torah calls 'Rishon HaShanah'" That's about as disgustingly misleading a quote as one could possibly imagine. The Torah calls the month of Nissan (not just 1 Nissan) the Rishon leChodshei HaShana, the first of the months of the year.

Comment: "they believed began in the month of Nisan" Which rabbis believe that? Not all do, and they don't believe it based on your misquoted verse. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: "six months late" The point in your title is to ask if it's early or late. Why take a side already?

Comment: According to this quote, the first day of the year was the Tishrei **before** the Nisan creation. However, the counting is from the Tishrei on which Hashem planned the creation. ` torahweb@torahweb.org subject: Rabbi Mordechai Willig The Months, Divine Attributes, and Purpose of Creation  Tosafos resolves the apparent contradiction as follows: in Tishrei it rose in thought to be created, but it was not created until Nissan.`

Answer (score 2):

While Nissan is the first month for numbering months, it isn't the first month of the calender year (i.e. what we use to calculate the number 5778).

The first Mishnah of Maseches Rosh Hashanah actually lists for different dates that are considered "new years", such as the fifteenth of Shevat as the new year for trees (according to Bais Hillel; this is what we call Tu B'Shvat).

Lehavdil, this is no different than how the secular calendar is run. January First is the first day of the calendar year, but you still have different dates for different "years". The US Government's fiscal year is September to August, the UK's tax year is April 6 - April 5, the academic year is September-August, etc.

Comment: "While Nissan is the first month for numbering months, it isn't the first month of the calender year (i.e. what we use to calculate the number 5778)." And what do we use to calculate the numbeer 5778?

Comment: @ninamag Tishrei/Rosh Hashanah

Comment: Shemot 12:2 הַחֹ֧דֶשׁ הַזֶּ֛ה לָכֶ֖ם ... לְחָדְשֵׁ֖י הַשָּׁנָֽה:
Exodus 12:2 This month shall be to you ... the first of the months of the year.

Comment: @ninamag Yes, this is how we count month numbers, as in Nissan is labeled "month 1", Iyar is labeled "month 2", etc. The Rashi you quote in the question explicitly says this. The calendar year starts in Tishrei, so while the month may be labeled "month 7", it's still the first month of the calendar year.

Comment: @ninamag That was the point. We number the months from Nisan, so 5778 begins on the first day of month 7. We number the years from Tishrei.

Comment: "The Torah Temima similarly writes ... for purposes of birkhat hachama, we follow the opinion of Rabbeinu Tam that the world was physically created in Nissan. However, we ... follow the opinion of Rabbeinu Tam that the world was created in thought on Tishrei. Since from a divine perspective there is no differentiation between thought and deed ..., the world is considered created by Hashem from the moment that the idea of creation was conceived, in accordance with the opinion of R’ Eliezer." - http://www.yutorah.org/togo/roshhashana/articles/Rosh_Hashanah_To-Go_-_5770_Rabbi_Reiss.pdf

Comment: @sabbahillel the rabbis I quoted believe that 5778 is based on the creation of the world, which they believe began on Nisan. The introduction of the rabbinical dating, which tomorrow will be 5778, on Tishrei, which the rabbis have every prerogative to do, is nevertheless six months late. This is clearly researched here: http://www.yutorah.org/togo/roshhashana/articles/Rosh_Hashanah_To-Go_-_5770_Rabbi_Reiss.pdf

Comment: @Salmononius2 When the rabbinical calendar starts is not my question. The answer I quoted shows that rabbis also believe that the year, and Creation, began in Nisan.

Comment: @Salmononius2 the New Year (mentioned in the Torah) takes place on 1 Nisan, which the Torah calls "Rishon HaShanah" (Shemot 12,2) רִאשׁוֹן... הַשָּׁנָה.

Comment: @ninamag You skipped 3 words in the middle, which changes the meaning to refer to naming standards (per Rashi).

Comment: @Salmononius2 if you are saying that Nisan is not "Rishon HaShanah", then you are like saying "Yom Rishon" is not the beginning of the week, but only of days.

Comment: @ninamag The passuk does not say "Rishon HaShanah"!

Comment: @ninamag A priori it's quite possible that Sunday could be the first day for the day count but not of the week count. It's also possible it happens to be both even if the name derives from only one of its functions. Indeed some count weeks from Wednesdays, which is why Havdala can be said until Tuesday.

Answer (score -2):

Why is the coming Rosh Hashana Year of 5778 six months late, that is the Rosh Hashana Year of 5778 actually began on 1 Nisan, as according to the following Torah Passage:

> Shemot 12:2 הַחֹ֧דֶשׁ הַזֶּ֛ה לָכֶ֖ם רֹ֣אשׁ חֳדָשִׁ֑ים רִאשׁ֥וֹן הוּא֙
>   לָכֶ֔ם לְחָדְשֵׁ֖י הַשָּׁנָֽה

The Torah calls the month of Nisan "Rishon HaShanah" (Shemot 12,2) רִאשׁוֹן... הַשָּׁנָה.

The answer I believe (the italics below is mine) is:

> "from the Sefer Or haChammah. A midrash in Bereishit Rabbah 10:4
>   states that the planets and spheres traveled at an extremely rapid
>   speed prior to the time of Adam’s sin (on the sixth day of creation).
>   According to this explanation, the planets traveled so fast that they
>   completed a six month journey in an actual time frame of two days
>   between the placement of the heavenly bodies in the firmament on the
>   fourth day of creation in tekufat Nissan, and the time of the creation
>   of man on the sixth day of creation. Consequently, even thought *the
>   world was created on the first day of Nissan, the sixth day of
>   creation actually took place on the first day of Tishrei.*"
>
> http://www.yutorah.org/togo/roshhashana/articles/Rosh_Hashanah_To-Go_-_5770_Rabbi_Reiss.pdf

The Rabbis, our Sages, created our calendar dating system, for example, 5778, based on and from the creation of the world, which they believe began on Nisan. The introduction of this rabbinical calendar dating, which tomorrow will be 5778, in the month of Tishrei, which the rabbis have every prerogative to do, is nevertheless six months late.

Comment: This is all just a HUGE misunderstanding.

Comment: @ezra which part? Do you not believe that our Sages started giving a year date to the world from the creation of the world?

Comment: Again, a misunderstanding. Have you read the answer from Salmononius2?

Comment: @ezra I understand, but you do understand the Torah refers to 1 Nisan as "Rishon HaShana"?

Comment: @ninamag False. The Torah does not refer to 1 Nisan as Rishon HaShana. It refers to the whole month of Nissan as the first month of the year.

Comment: @DoubleAA I can live with that, as long as you agree that the month of Nisan is Rishon HaShanah.

Comment: @ninamag How can I agree with that when it's completely false?? The month of Nissan is Rishon LeChodshei HaShana. There's nothing to argue about when the verse is explicit! Leaving out words to make up claims is literally stupid.

Comment: @DoubleAA please pardon my stupidity, but if you are saying that Nisan is not "Rishon HaShanah", then you are like saying "Yom Rishon" is not the beginning of the week, but only of days, no?

Comment: @ninamag Yom Rishon of what?

Comment: @DoubleAA just Yom Rishon HaShavua as in Sunday (from motzaei Shabbat til Sunday sundown).

Comment: @ninamag I'm not sure I've ever heard of "Yom Rishon HaShavua" or if that even grammatically makes any sense.

Comment: @ninamag - But just as Monday is the first day of the workweek, Rosh HaShanah is the first month of the year while actually being the seventh month from Nissan, the first month.

Comment: @DoubleAA yom rishon as in the first day of the week, the shavua

Comment: @ninamag Did you make that title up? Maybe Sunday is called Yom Rishon because it's the first day since Shabbat? "יום ראשון לשבת"

Comment: @DoubleAA 'Maybe Sunday is called Yom Rishon because it's the first day since Shabbat? "יום ראשון לשבת"' - that lamed can be translated as "of", as in the "first day of the week".

Comment: @nima indeed that is possible.