# Birchas Hachama and the world being created in Tishrei

Tags: blessing, time, creation

Birchas Hachama is said once every 28 years. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkat_Hachama) it is said when the sun has returned to ts original position when the world was created.

> Jewish tradition says that when the Sun completes this cycle, it has
>   returned to its position when the world was created.

According to the [Rabbi Dovid Heber from the Star-K](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/679/birchas-hachama-5769/) in the footnotes number 11 this is based on the opinion of Rebbi Yehoshua that the world was created in Nissan.

As far as I know and from the [answer here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/63897/what-is-the-real-first-month-of-the-jewish-year/63899#63899) the accepted month of the creation of the world is Tishrei.

I have not found anyone suggesting that we should say Birchas Hachama in Tishrei. Why?

Comment: "the accepted month of the creation of the world is Tishrei" What does that even mean? And even R Yehoshua agrees that the holiday of Rosh Hashana is on 1 Tishrei.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/820926/jewish/In-Depth.htm http://www.mykosherhome.com/index.php?csstype=articlepublished&articleid=386&article=true

Comment: Rabbi Heber said in a shiur we hold like both. Depends which context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dispute you quote regarding when the world was created is that of R’ Eliezer and R’ Yehoshua, in Rosh HaShanah 10b-12a. At the end of that discussion, the Gemara sticks in this Braisa. Translation is mine; the brackets are from Rashi.

> ת"ר חכמי ישראל מונין למבול כר"א ולתקופה כר' יהושע חכמי אומות העולם מונין אף למבול כר' יהושע:
>
> The Sages taught in a Braisa: The Jewish scholars count [years from] the Flood [and Creation, etc.] according to R’ Eliezer [who holds that the world was created in Tishrei], and they count the [solar and lunar] cycles according to R’ Yehoshua [who holds that the world was created in Nissan]. The non-Jewish scholars count even [the years from] the Flood [etc.] according to R’ Yehoshua.

Rashi (end of DH Chachmei Yisrael) explains this dichotomy:

> ולא משום דסבירא להו בתשרי נברא העולם אלא דתשרי ראש השנה לשנים ובניסן נברא העולם כדקתני:
>
> Not because they hold that the world was created in Tishrei, but rather that Tishrei is the Rosh HaShanah for years [and therefore we count years from Tishrei], and in Nissan the world was created [and therefore we count the solar and lunar cycles from Nissan].

Comment: Whose interpretations are in the parentheses - that's not what's written in the Gemmorah?

Comment: “Translation is mine; the brackets are from Rashi.” I’m paraphrasing Rashi, of course, but if you read him inside, it’s all there.